# An easy way to define $\exp(x)$ - does it work?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

$\exp(x)$ is usually defined in three different ways:

1) By its Taylor series: $\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

2) By its derivative: $\exp(x)'=\exp(x)$

3) By the limit $\exp(x)=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{N} \right)^N$

In textbooks they mostly use the 3rd way, because $\exp(x)$ is introduced before the derivative.

---

But it just occured to me - we don't need this much information to define this function. There is a very simple definition which allows to recover all the other properties:

4)

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \exp(x)  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+x)$$

Now, it's just two terms of Taylor expansion - it doesn't seem like much. Yet we can prove the following properties:

a) It follows that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \exp(a x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \exp^a(x)$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \exp^a(x)  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+x)^a = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+a x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \exp(a x)$$

b) Using this property we recover the 3rd definition

$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{N} \right)^N=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \exp \left(\frac{x}{N}\right) \right)^N=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( \exp^{\frac{1}{N}}(x) \right)^N=\exp(x)
$$

Does this work, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

**Edit**

I was obviously wrong - there is an infinite number of functions with the property 4. So the definition needs to be:

4) For $x \rightarrow 0$
$$ \exp(x)  \approx 1+x$$

For any $x$

$$\exp^a(x)  = \exp(a x)$$

Comment: Your definition (4) is satisfied by *any* function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 1$, so there is no way that you can prove $f(x)=\exp(x)$ from it...

Comment: If $a$ is real, how do you define $\text{thing}^a$?

Comment: As $(\exp(x))^a$

Comment: See the edit of my previous  comment.

Comment: $\approx$ doesn't have a standard meaning. However, if we define $f(x)\approx g(x)$ to mean $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}x=0$, then $\exp(x)\approx 1+x$ is actually equivalent to $\exp'(0)=\exp(0)$. Along with the rule $\exp(a)\exp(b)=\exp(a+b)$, this would imply $\exp'(x)=\exp(x)$ (why?), which is the second definition at the top.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, As anyone does - if $a$ is a limit of Cauchy sequence of *rational* numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_k$ then $y^a$ is a limit of $y^{a_k}$. How does it relate to my question at all

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla If $a$ is real and $\rm thing$ is positive, it's easy to define…

Comment: @YuriyS In any case, I think it might be better to use the rule $\exp(a)\exp(b)=\exp(a+b)$, just because it sidesteps the whole Cauchy-sequence-exponentiation thing.

Comment: Another nice way to define $\exp(x)$ is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627497/the-functional-inequality-fx-ge-x1-fxfy-le-fxy/). The link refers to a related question: it states that $f(x)f(y)\leq f(x+y)$ and $f(x)\geq x+1$, and you can prove from only those two that $f(x)=\exp(x)$. Not at all an answer to your question, but if we're listing the possible ways to define $\exp(x)$, then I'd like to include this one :)

Comment: What about defining $log$ as the integral of $\frac 1 x$ and $exp$ as its inverse?  Maybe not the best but it should be a candidate.

Comment: @badjohn, it's a classic, and I agree that it's a very nice way to define it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)$$ is simply equal to $1$, so the equation you wrote is equal to the equation $$\lim_{x\to0} \exp(x) = 1$$

which is most certainly **not** enough to characterise the exponential function, for example $\cos(x)$.

---

As for what you proved in points (a) and (b), I don't even know what you were intending to prove so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it, see the edit

Comment: I wanted to write $\exp(x) \approx 1+x$ for $x \rightarrow 0$ at first, would it be better?

Comment: @YuriyS Not really, since the function $1+x$ also satisfies that condition.

Comment: And together with the property $\exp^a(x)=\exp(ax)$?

Comment: @YuriyS That might be enough, yes. But I'm not sure. Also, I don't see the benefit of such a definition.